# [CodeEval][GO] CodeEval Error: Process was aborted due to timeout

Tags: go, timeout

I was trying to submit my solution of https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/158/ it's a bubble sort. I code in GO lang and on my PC it runs fine and fast! I tried utilize code example of go's input and I tried my own piece of code too.

Anyone can help me ? I tried change the code in somehow, but nothing worked.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a certain edge case you are probably missing in your code. See https://getsatisfaction.com/codeeval/topics/bubble-sort-iterations-are-too-high-causing-solution-to-be-aborted-in-java

Comment: I edited my question with the sample code. I spent some time on it and i can't see how to make it faster o0.. I don't know HOW CodeEval stops due to timeout. Only if they have a TXT file with a HUGE iterations, but even though it will request a huge time to do a huge iterations in almost any machine.

Comment: Few punches in the head and it works, following the logic on this link. Thanks!